# pushing complete python list to oracle db using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, database, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I have two list having 100 elements in each (say `class_db_col`, and `class_id_col`). I want to push all the items in `class_db_col` list to one column (say `class_result`) present in oracle DB.

```
statement = 'update TRANSFERS_TXN_MT set CLASS_RESULT = :1 where id= :2'
for i in range(len(class_db_col)):
     cursor.execute(statement,(class_id_col[i],class_db_col[i]))
conn.commit()
```

getting this error

> ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statement

can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Which version of cx_Oracle are you using?

Comment: @APC cx-Oracle==6.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of tuples you can use cursor.executemany() instead. It looks like you have two parallel arrays which you can create tuples out of via this code:

data = list(zip(class_id_col, class_db_col))

This should result in an array that looks like this:

[(1, 4), (2, 6), ..., (8, 15)]

Then you can use this code:

cursor.executemany("update TRANSFERS_TXN_MT set CLASS_RESULT = :1 where id = :2", data)