# Error while retrieving records from oracle table with respect to ID in csv file

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I want to pass the IDs (in the sampledata.csv) as an argument in the SQL query and fetch the IDs and respective CREATED_TIME from the Oracle table.

## sampledata.csv  (I have more than 5K records in the original file)

```
ID
909650124
905901916
908667528
907963151
908610211
907671207
909164586
905595841
908785942
908785942
```

## DB Table data

```
ID  CREATED_DATE
909650124   03/18/2019 04:37:43 PM
905901916   03/15/2019 11:20:55 PM
908667528   03/15/2019 02:37:16 PM
907963151   03/08/2019 03:19:09 PM
908610211   03/08/2019 03:06:17 PM
907671207   03/07/2019 01:06:58 AM
909164586   03/06/2019 01:42:20 AM
905595841   03/04/2019 11:24:31 PM
908785942   03/03/2019 10:09:40 PM
908785942   03/01/2019 07:51:51 AM
```

I tried to fetch the data using simple SQL statement using Toad but the records are more than 10K and I want to automate it.

## first.py script

```
import os
import csv
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='USER_NAME', password='USER_PASSWORD', dsn=r'DSN_STRING')
db = conn.cursor()

def main():

    f = open("sampledata.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for id in reader:
        db.execute("SELECT id, created_date FROM userdata_table WHERE merch_order_id = :id",
                     {'id': id})
        print(f"{id}  {created_date}")

    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## second.py script

```
import os
import csv

import cx_Oracle

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(r'oracle+cx_oracle://USER_NAME:USER_PASSWORD@DSN_STRING'))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():

    f = open("sampledata.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print(reader)

    for id in reader:
        db.execute("SELECT id, created_date FROM userdata_table WHERE id = :id",{'id': id})
        print(f"{id}  {created_date}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the above code, I tried to read the IDs in the CSV file and then passed the IDs into the SQL statement but getting below error. Can someone please help me on this to understand where it went wrong and how to correct that?

=================================================================

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL
>   statements

Comment: `id` should not be array. Try `int(id[0])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pushing complete python list to oracle db using cx\_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315383/pushing-complete-python-list-to-oracle-db-using-cx-oracle)